# Basic transistor circuit

Tags: transistors, led, npn

I'm playing around with a BD179 transistor, trying to get my LED bulb to light up but without luck. My mistake is probably something very simple but I'm learning so bear with me.

[image]

Comment: Please label the connections for the LM2596

Comment: @DKNguyen it's Vin on the right and Vout on the left, respectively black wires are - and red is +12V yellow is the stepped down 3.4V. Since it's not an isolated circuit I connected the - of the LED to the Vout of the converter because it was easier for me physically but should be the same as connecting it to the - of my power supply.

Comment: Your schematic is extremely difficult to understand as you're not following standard circuit conventions as: ground at the bottom, supply/battery at left or right etc. Have a look at how similar schematics are drawn and follow that. I agree with DKNguyen that you need to add the names of the pins of the DCDC module. Adding a text like you just did is not sufficient. We're here to help but we do expect that you make things as clear as possible.

Comment: Without a decent ground reference I have not idea how this is supposed to work. What I can tell is that transistors work much better with the LED at the collector side.

Comment: Also your LED is in series with the emitter of the NPN, that means the NPN will not work as a switch and you will not get the voltage you (probably) want across the LED. Also why step down to 3.4 V, that makes no sense. Yes you're learning, **good**. Here's a tip: go search how others switch on/off LEDs using a transistor. Then **do the same**. Trying to "figure it out on your own" is a **recipe for disaster** because: it will extremely likely not work and/or might also damage components.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie There, I hope it's better now. Essentially I'm trying to switch a higher load from a microcontroller, I'm simulating it here with this ~3V. It's an LED Bulb, not a simple LED.

Comment: @DKNguyen it's an ultralux lg1216642 but I'm not sure you will find it online I believe it's produced locally.

Comment: That's all we need to know about the LED. We're just basically wondering if it's already equipped internally to be hooked directly to 12V

Comment: @DKNguyen yes it has a circuit, if I connect it to my power supply directly it works fine. I'm having trouble understanding the transistor part obviously :(

Comment: Please *edit the text of your question* to indicate that you're working with an LED *bulb* and not an LED, and outline the drive requirements of the thing (I assume that it wants 12V, and consumes 500mA -- but *you* need to verify that and say so, or post a link to a data sheet).

Comment: That's somewhat better indeed. That LED seems designed for 12 V so it has internal resistors. Still there is **no point** to make the 3.3 V. Also that 3.3 V will result in 3.3 - 0.7 = 2.6 V across the LED (due to the way you connected it) so it is not going to light up. I suggest you remove the DCDC and connect the 2k base resistor to +12 V (instead of 3.3 V). Then connect the LED in series with the collector of the NPN (instead of the emitter). Read this to learn how that works: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_4.html

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie problem is this is just a test setup. I'll be switching the transistor from a microcontroller which has only 3.3V, so I've either got the wrong transistor or I wired it incorrectly. I suppose it's likely the latter.

Comment: your question is much easier to understand after those edits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two potential problems in your circuit.

### 1. The 2kOhm base resistor is too high.

By applying 3.4V through a 2K resistor, and accounting for the base-emitter voltage drop of the BJT (in the datasheet) you get a base current of:

\$ I_{collector} = \frac{V_{supply} - V_{be}} {R_{base}} = \frac{3.4V - 1.3V} {2kOhm} = 1.05mA\$

In the datasheet, the BJT's DC current gain ranges anywhere from 15 to 160 which means your collector current will be anywhere between 15 to 160 times the base current which is 16mA to 168mA.

But your bulb is a 12V, 6W bulb which means it runs at:
\$ I = \frac{P}{V} = \frac{6W}{12V} = 500mA\$

### 2. The LED should be on the collector side of the transistor.

Put simply, the current flowing between the base and emitter terminals of an BJT determine how much it turns on by. The BJT can ONLY see the voltage difference between its terminals. It does not and cannot know about voltages anywhere else.

Your power supply is applying to the base resistor relative to ground. But the voltage and current parameters that the BJT actually cares about are those between the base and emitter terminals. If your source pin is not connected to ground then what you BJT cares about is not the same as what the supply is providing. Things get distorted

As the transistor turns on and conducts current through your bulb, the voltage across the bulb rises pushing the source terminal voltage away from ground which reduces the base-emitter voltage difference (and the voltage across the base resistor which reduces the base current). This acts as negative feedback and fights the transistor turning on more.

This negative feedback has its uses, but not when using the transistor as a plain old switch. It's mostly for amplifiers and analog circuits.

Comment: So if I understand this right, I need to move the bulb before the transistor on the 12V line and I need to increase the current on the base.

Comment: Yes. This is filler text.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's a dumb question but why does it make a difference whether the load is before or after the transistor on the collector-emitter path?

Comment: @php_nub_qq Read the part about the transistor only being able to care about the base and source. Read it carefully. It's the most important thing in there.

Comment: Huge gratitude for the time you took to explain this to me like to a complete moron. Little feedback - I just switched the bulb to the collector side and it immediately lit up. I then switched to a 370 ohm resistor since that's the lowest I have laying around and it seems to be as bright as if I connect it to the supply directly.

Comment: @php_nub_qq It's a common issue. It's usually the first difficulty people have about transistors.

Comment: @php_nub_qq: also, look for information on emitter follower circuits - that's what you have there.  In an emitter follower, the emitter voltage will "follow" the base voltage, but, for an NPN, will be about 0.7 volts below the base.

Comment: @php_nub_qq Now you have the limited MCU pin drive current issue that TimWescott is referring to.

Comment: Yep I will most likely have to find a suitable FET transistor for the job.

Comment: OR, I could just use another of the same transistor that will be switched from the MCU with say 5mA which will then allow more than 50 mA to flow on the collector side (connected to the 12V supply), which will then feed into the base of the transistor for the bulb?

Comment: @php_nub_qq Yes. This is basically choosing a BJT with a higher beta. BJTs designed specifically for the highest possible beta are called "super-beta" transistors. There are also Darlingtons which is basically one BJT feeding the base of another BJT. Both of which were referred to by TimeWescott in ihs answer. You could also do something similar yourself with two discrete transistors.

Comment: @DKNguyen well at least for a moment there I felt smart. Anyway, not gonna spam here anymore, again huge thank you.

Comment: Little feedback continuation - I thought I was using a 370 ohm resistor, though I measured it and it turned out to be a 170 ohm one. I was curious how much current does the circuit consume so I connected the bulb directly and measured 650mA, then I added it to the circuit and measured 370mA, which if I'm correct means the bulb is not fully powered although it visually appears to be, which raises another question - should I use a lower resistance in order to allow more current or should I leave it the way it is since it's bright enough and I could save on a couple hundred mA.

Comment: @php_nub_qq The main issue with not turning on the transistor as much as possible is it means the transistor is heating up more than it needs since it is acting like a lossy switch (entering territory where it acts more as an amplifier than a switch). Any voltage not being dropped across the load is being dropped across the switch. If the load current is high enough, this is significant power wasted and causing heating in the MOSFET

Comment: @php_nub_qq Transistors have their limits so you can't just keep increasing base current (for BJTs) or gate voltage (for MOSFETs) and expect the current through the collector current (for BJT) or drain current (for MOSFETs) to continually increase. It eventually levels off depending on the size of the transistor.

Comment: @DKNguyen well for the BD179 I have it is rated at 3A (Ic) so it's plenty above the 650mA the bulb needs alone. If the entire circuit is drawing 370mA, as measured, then even if the BJT is heating up more than it should I'm still saving on almost twice the power I would use to power the bulb fully, isn't that a win anyway? 3W of power saved (12v x 280mA) multiplied by 6 (the number of bulbs I have) could add up along with other small optimizations like this and increase my battery life noticeably. This is all just theory, I'm probably not going to end up using BJTs for this.

Answer (score 6):

As designed, your circuit is an emitter follower.  You're applying 3.4V to the base of an NPN, and taking power off of the emitter.  The transistor will try to hold the emitter voltage at roughly \$V_{be} - 0.7\mathrm{V}\$, or about 2.7V.  That's not nearly enough for your LED.

You want something like the following.

You need to choose a transistor that can pass 500mA (because it's a 6W, 12V "bulb" -- that works out to half an amp).  Then you need to choose a resistor that'll cause the transistor to turn on hard.  If you used a 2N4401, you'd need about 50mA into the base -- that would require a resistance of \$R_1 = \mathrm{(3.4V - 0.7V) / (50mA)} = 54\Omega\$.

**However**, you have a problem, because you mentioned that you're driving this from a microcontroller, and there aren't any microcontrollers out there that can drive \$50\mathrm{mA}\$.  So you either need to use a Darlington (which has a higher collector-emitter drop than a plain BJT), or you need to search around for a "super beta" transistor (they're out there, and they're nice -- look for high \$H_{FE}\$ in saturation), or you need to use a logic-level FET that's rated for a gate voltage of 3.3V

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fleZUM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>